# How do I use $timeout service in a Directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, angularjs-timeout

Basically, I want to measure the width of the element after angular has manipulated the DOM. So I would like to use $timeout for that, but it keeps getting me errors.

HTML

```
   <div ng-app="github">
      <ul mynav>
        <li ng-repeat="nav in navItems">{{nav.name}}</li>
      </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
ul,li {
  display:inline-block;
}
li {
  margin-right:1em;
}
```

JS

```
(function() {
  angular.module('github', [])
    .directive('mynav', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, timeout) {
          scope.navItems = [{
            "name": "home"
          }, {
            "name": "link1"
          }, {
            "name": "link2"
          }, {
            "name": "link3"
          }];
          timeout(function() {
            console.log($(element).width());
          })
        }

      }
    });
})();
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/artvader/pen/NAkVYW

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`link` function isn't a correct place to inject dependency. It has defined sequence of parameter like I shown below. You can't put dependency there.

> ```
> link(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
> ```

Inject `$timeout` dependency in directive `function`.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('github', [])
    .directive('mynav', function($window, $timeout) { //<-- dependency injected here
      return {
```

Then just use injected `$timeout` inside `link` function

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log(element.width());
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    // code here
    $scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

$apply is included as a reminder that since this is an external jQuery call you need to tell angular to update the DOM.

$timeout being an angular version automatically updates the DOM

Comment: Don't encourage to use `$apply`, its bad pattern to use, Though `$timeout` does help to update **bindings** not **DOM**

Answer (score -2):

Just replace timeout with setinterval like below:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('github', [])
    .directive('mynav', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, timeout) {
          scope.navItems = [{
            "name": "home"
          }, {
            "name": "link1"
          }, {
            "name": "link2"
          }, {
            "name": "link3"
          }];
          setInterval(function() { // replpace 'timeout' with 'setInterval'
            console.log($(element).width());
          })
        }

      }
    });
})();
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: bad idea, you should use angular dependencies, otherwise you will be need to call `$apply` method to update scope.